# discordjs-self-v13 button click is not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am a Python programmer and new to JavaScript so maybe I got something wrong but the button click function on discordjs-self-v13 is not working for me when using coordinates or customID. I am trying to click the claim button as shown below:
[image]

Below is my code which currently doesn't work but doesn't throw any errors either:

```
//Auto Claim
client.on('messageCreate', async msg=>{
    if(!takingOrders||actualOrders>=data.maxClaims||!data.servers[msg.guildId]||(claims[msg.guildId]&&claims[msg.guildId]>=data.servers[msg.guildId].maxClaim)||!msg.components[0]||data.blacklist[msg.channel.parentId
])return;
    msg.components[0].components.forEach(async component=>{
        if(component.type=='BUTTON'&&component.label=='Claim'){
            var responseTime = data.randomDelay&&data.delay+Math.random().toFixed(3)*data.delay||data.delay;
            claims[msg.guildId] = claims[msg.guildId]&&claims[msg.guildId]+1||1;actualOrders++;
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log('['+msg.guild.name+'] Claimed within '+(responseTime/1000)+" seconds");
                console.log('['+msg.guild.name+'] Claimed orders: '+claims[msg.guildId]);
                console.log('Active orders: '+actualOrders);
                msg.clickButton(component.customId).catch(e=>{console.log('An error ocurred!',e)});;
        },responseTime);
        }
    });
});
```

I also tried to do it through coordinates but that doesn't work either:
`msg.clickButton({ X: 1, Y: 0 }).catch(e=>{console.log('An error ocurred!',e)});;`

It seems to be able to detect the button since I get the console output and it also does work if I only write:
`msg.clickButton().catch(e=>{console.log('An error ocurred!',e)});;`
But that clicks the Close button instead of the Claim button. I have already tried all the methods mentioned in the documentation and the only one that seems to be working for me is if I don't pass any parameters and it just click the first button. Here is the documentation if needed: https://discordjs-self-v13.netlify.app/#/docs/docs/main/class/Message?scrollTo=clickButton

I am starting to suspect that the module is outdated...

Thanks a lot for your time and effort